# Is using Bootstrap classes in React an antipattern?

Tags: css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, sass, react-bootstrap

I'm having difficulty defining a consistent styling pattern when using react with bootstrap. I am using a lot of custom selectors with BEM naming and mixing with Bootstrap classes seems like a bad idea. It seems like a better fit for react to separate the css into modules without bootstrap classes at all, however I felt like defining the same styling per-selector for a bootstrap class that already exists would increase the size of the css files overall.

For Example:

```
<div className="my-component mt-2 mb-3 px-4 d-flex align-items-center">
<p className="my-component__text mb-0 text-center font-weight-bold text-success">text</p>
</div>
```

In this example it might make more sense to reduce all of the bootstrap spacing classes in to the single "my-component" class, but I'm not sure if that would negatively impact performance. What is the best way to go about styling when using react and bootstrap in an application?

Comment: Read this blog brother. https://blog.logrocket.com/how-to-use-bootstrap-with-react-a354715d1121/#:~:text=Add%20Bootstrap%20to%20React,as%20bootstrap%2Dreact%20or%20reactstrap%20)